# Polygon from json file to Postgres geometry format

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a Json file with zip code and polygon data. I want to convert and store polygon to a Postgres table in geometry data type. My postgres 9.5 with PostGIS extensions.

my file : `myjson.json`

data:

```
{
  "zipcode": "97358",
  "polygon": [
    {
      "lat": 44.730418,
      "lng": -122.544798
    },
    {
      "lat": 44.763411,
      "lng": -122.685015
    },
    {
      "lat": 44.831045,
      "lng": -122.616831
    },
    {
      "lat": 44.863487,
      "lng": -122.401282
    },
    {
      "lat": 44.80795,
      "lng": -122.40953
    },
    {
      "lat": 44.730418,
      "lng": -122.544798
    }
  ]
}
```

Postges mytable: zipcode varchar, polygon geometry

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but this should do the trick:

`WITH polygon AS (
  SELECT json_array_elements(t->'polygon')
  AS data FROM json($$
{
  "zipcode": "97358",
  "polygon": [
    {"lat": 44.730418, "lng": -122.544798},
    {"lat": 44.763411, "lng": -122.685015},
    {"lat": 44.831045, "lng": -122.616831},
    {"lat": 44.863487, "lng": -122.401282},
    {"lat": 44.80795,  "lng": -122.40953},
    {"lat": 44.730418, "lng": -122.544798}
  ]
}$$) as t)
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeometryFromText(
  'LINESTRING(' || string_agg((p.data->'lng')::text || 
  ' ' || (p.data->'lat')::text, ',') || ')', 4326)) 
  FROM polygon AS p;`

Note that I've hard-coded the SRID (projection) as 4326. If this polygon isn't in Oregon then you probably need to correct it.

Comment: Thank you, It works for one row record. It didn't work when used data from Postres table. First, I insert data from json file into a table and extract the zip code with polygon ( geometry format) information from this a table by using this recommended script. Any suggestions pls